# Adding css class to element with jQuery dynamicly

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, dynamic

i have one question. Can i set dynimacly class attributes to an element on page with jquery?

Codes Example:

html

```
 ...
 <div id="example">
    ...
 </div>
 <div id="example2">
    ...
 </div>
...
```

css

```
 #example{
      background-color:red;
 }
```

jquery - this is what i want to do

```
 // Its just example how it have to works but i need other way in jQuery
 $('#example').click(function(){
      var class = createClass();
      var color = $(this).css('background-color');
      class.css('background-color', color);
      $('#example2').addClass(class);
 });
```

It is crucial to make it in this way. Because jquery adds css attributes direct to an element in his HTML code, but i need create Class with attributes and give it to one element  element and then i want remove in one row ***$('#example2').removeClass(class);***

Thanks for any response.

Comment: You are asking how to create rule-sets, not classes.

Comment: awesome, awesome, awesome.... really thanks!

Comment: how i can give you gold vote? :v

Comment: @user2899587 You can't, but the biggest help you can give us is reading the documentation next time ;).